# OOP on Tkinter (connect classes)

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to learn OOP using tkinter. I want to create two classes, one for the main Frame and the other for a simple Label, and then grid the Label to the Frame with an OOP approach.

Something like...

```
import tkinter as tk

class main_frame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

class label1(tk.Label):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Label.__init__(self)
        #label = tk.Label(main_frame, text='lol')???

root = tk.Tk()
main_frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
#label1(main_frame).grid(row=1,column=0) ???
root.mainloop()
```

My code might not be making any sense compared to a correct OOP approach to this. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your question? What part of the problem are you struggling with?

Comment: and what is the problem ? Do you get erorr message ? Do you have any question ?

Answer (score 0):

The `main_frame` widget needs to be a child of the `Tk` window, and then the `label1` widget needs to be a child of the of the `main_frame` widget. Here is my solution:

```
import tkinter as tk

class main_frame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = label1(self)
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

class label1(tk.Label):

    def __init__ (self, master, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, text="test")

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainframe = main_frame(root)
root.mainframe.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note how each widget passes itself as `master` to each other widget.